# iam unable to applybindings in knockout is this correct approach?

Tags: knockout.js

i have two view models and i want applybindings one view modek is Div specific and the other one is full page

```
var profileModel = {
first: ko.observable("Bob"),
last: ko.observable("Smith")
 };

var shellModel = {
header: ko.observable("Administration"),
sections: ["profile", "settings", "notifications"],
selectedSection: ko.observable()
};

 ko.applyBindings(shellModel);
 ko.applyBindings(profileModel, document.getElementById("profile"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Jairam you can make a object with two view model and applybindings to object:

```
 var profileModel = {
    first: ko.observable("Bob"),
    last: ko.observable("Smith")
     };

    var shellModel = {
    header: ko.observable("Administration"),
    sections: ["profile", "settings", "notifications"],
    selectedSection: ko.observable()
    };

    var viewModel = {
      subModelA: profileModel ,
      subModelB: shellModel 
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `ko.applyBindings(...)` to the same parent element or even a child element within the same parent.

When you call `ko.applyBindings(shellModel)`, you're binding your model to the entire DOM, and later, you start other bindings in a child element of your same document.

If you want to do so, merge both view models into one and execute a `ko.applyBindings(mergedModel)` and it should work in your scenario. Or call `ko.applyBindings(...)` for `shellModel` to a concrete element which shouldn't be a parent of `profile`.

Comment: how to merge two models in applybindings

Comment: @jairamchakravarthi Use your mind, my friend! ;) You don't merge them in the `applyBindings`.... You merge two view models into one in your own code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, it sort of merges the two viewmodels. Sort of like inheritance, viewmodel2 inherits all of viewmodel1's attributes.

```js
function viewModel1() {
  var self = this;

  self.vm1Alert = function() {
    alert('Model 1 stuff')
  };
}


function viewModel2() {
  var self = this;

  viewModel1.call(self);
  self.vm1Alert(); //from the first viewmodel
  alert('Model 2 stuff');

}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel2());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```