# how to bind several view models in a single page using knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to set my page up as a single page app using knockout, I have split it up as shown in the following picture but have no idea as to how to bind several viewModels into the same html page.
[image]

Comment: looks like a job for ajax! loading the different html viewmodel 'pages' via ajax requests...

Comment: Use a SPA engine like Durandal

Comment: Take a look at [Viewmodel merging][1] on how to merge a couple of viewmodels into 1


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294373/iam-unable-to-applybindings-in-knockout-is-this-correct-approach/29342312#29342312

Comment: You can try this [Links 2 viewmodels  together][1].
You can use this to merge 2 or more view models


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294373/iam-unable-to-applybindings-in-knockout-is-this-correct-approach/29342312#29342312

Comment: Merging 2 or more view models

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294373/iam-unable-to-applybindings-in-knockout-is-this-correct-approach/29342312#29342312

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, element)` to apply bindings to different elements, using different ViewModels like this:  You cannot bind more than one viewModel to the same element or knockout will throw an error.

```
// Element
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel(), element);

// Element 1
var element1 = document.getElementById('myElement1');
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel1(), element1);
```

You can read more about this here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the reference docs:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

the `ko.applyBindings` function takes two params, the first is the viewmodel, the second (optional) is the dom element to which it should be applied. You can apply multiple viewmodels to each container element on your page.

```
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel1, $("#container1")[0]);
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel2, $("#container2")[0]);
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel3, $("#container3")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, element)
```

OR

"With" binding

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?